# Firebase Cloud Messaging on Python clients

Tags: python-3.x, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, messaging

I'm new to Firebase cloud services, I have a scenario in which multiple clients running Python need to communicate via text and or audio messages. For this I'm considering FireBase Cloud Messaging. But there seems to be no API for python clients. Is there anyway to still use Firebase for Python clients?

Comment: You can check the official documentation. https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/start there are a couple of libraries under python.

Comment: The link you sent is for database not a messaging application, not sure how much the commands for the two overlap.

Answer (score 0):

This is a few months old, but since I ended up here while searching for the same problem...

I use **[PyFCM](https://github.com/olucurious/PyFCM)**, which is a simple Python API for FireBase Cloud Messaging.

*Please note I have only tested this library to send notifications to Android devices from a remote server :)*